# How do I redirect a subdirectory with Yoast SEO pro?

Tags: redirects, wordpress, 301-redirect, yoast

I have changed shop section name from "product" to "shop".

I have yoast seo pro and i can do redirect with that plugin. How do I  redirect all pages from old addresses to new ones
from `example.ir/product/...` to `example.ir/shop/...`

Comment: Why not look into their documentation or contact them for support?

Comment: Using SEO and Tools, you can edit your .htaccess file.  The Redirect tab under Tools is for only files AFAIK.

Comment: https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/ This plugin is much better for what you are trying to accomplish. Over a million installs - it will save you a lot of time!